# Using DollarPGestureRecognizer in webView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, gesture

I am trying to use `DollarPGestureRecognizer` to `webView` in iOS. I've followed the process to recognize it on `webView` both programmatically and using storyboard, but its throwing exception on `GestureView.h` file's `drawRect` method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    NSLog(@"I'm just here, got me!!");

    for (int i = 0; i < [completeStrokes count]; i++) {
        Stroke *stroke = [completeStrokes objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Welcome to the freakshow");
        [self drawStroke:stroke inContext:context];
    }

    for (NSValue *touchValue in currentTouches) {
        Stroke *stroke = [currentTouches objectForKey:touchValue];
        [self drawStroke:stroke inContext:context];
    }
}
```

its not entering the first loop and throwing

> Thread1_EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code1).

To enable gesture on `webView` I also implemented `UIWebViewDelegate` method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

I am not getting the actual problem.

Comment: Well after googling a lot, i come to know that to activate touch event in UIWebView the following tutorial seems interesting 
http://wyldco.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-capture-touches-over-a-uiwebview/

Answer (score 0):

As here webview is loading an html page, so DollarPGestureRecognizer library for ObjectiveC will not work. The recognizer itself has library in javascript to work on html. 
https://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/pdollar.js

I didn't implement the javascript library. Enthusiast should go for it. And this recognizer for ObjectiveC does not support webview and imageview in iOS.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.